# How to make this code throw AssertionError as the author said in JCIP

Tags: java

Below code are from `Java Concurrency in Practice`

```
//Listing 3.14 Unsafe publication
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
    holder = new Holder(42);
}

//Listing 3.15
public class Holder {
    private int n;
    public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }
    public void assertSanity() {
        if (n != n)
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
    }
}
```

The author said:

> In
>   fact, if the Holder in Listing 3.15 is published using the unsafe publication idiom
>   in Listing 3.14, and a thread other than the publishing thread were to call
>   assertSanity, it could throw AssertionError!

Could anybody provide some code snippet that can lead to the AssertionError as the author said?

Thanks